# Triggering an on the fly download in ext-js

Tags: file, extjs, download

I have a grid in ext-js with a "Download" button so that the user can download a file representation of that grid that I will create on the fly when the button is pushed.

But I don't know by what mechanism in EXT-JS I can trigger this download.  Not sure if EXT-JS has some helper functions, or if you just use straight javascript (in which case how do you get down to the internals to do it in EXT-JS?)

What's the best approach to trigger this download from the button handler function?

Comment: Why can't you use handler or service call where you post the Grid's store data in and populate the file with that data? I believe you trying to implement something like 'Export to Excel' type of functionality.

Comment: I have no problem putting the formatting of the file together.  What I am missing is how to induce the browser to download a string generated by my javascript program as a file from within the EXT-JS framework.  Yes, Export to Excel is about right-- actually my final destination is Word.  Using the XML format of word and a template I think that should be ok, I'm just unclear on the mechanics of starting the download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ExtJS Button class has an href property that can be set to trigger an HTTP GET of the resource you are trying to fetch.

EDIT: after the clarification of what you are trying to do here is what you need:
Data on the URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

This trick makes your browser think it needs to download a file. You have to produce the data on the client side. There are some plugins that work this way: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?146348-ExtJS-4-Grid-Printer-Plugin

Another plugin uses a different method: https://github.com/iwiznia/Ext.ux.Exporter

Comment: Unfortunately that's part of the trick of this one-- I'm generating the file on the fly from the data in the grid, so there is no file or resource to get per se.  It will be generated on the client side.

Comment: You led me to the answer, thanks!  I just need to call window.location.href = uri where uri is a string that contains the document plus header as per wikipedia article above.  That call alone induces (a modern) browser to download.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location = url_of_file
```

Though I recall some issues with strange behavior in ExtJS, so we normally open the url in a new window/tab:

```
window.open(url_of_file);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's part of the trick of this one-- I'm generating the file on the fly from the data in the grid, so there is no file or resource to get per se.  It will be generated on the client side.

Comment: How are you generating a file with Javascript?

Comment: I'm going to step through the grid, take the info that I need and format it.  But I'm not worried about that part-- imagine I generate a text file from a string.  In the button handler, how do I induce the browser to download it as a file?

Comment: well, you can't generate a file with javascript, unless you use the HTML5 filewriter. this can create a temporary "fake" url. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: you can also consider running your extjs app in a desktop app, like firefox web apps, or using flash, or using java, or using activex

Comment: See answer above-- looks like a call to window.location.href = uri was what I was looking for